# Loading static project without webpack or CDNs

Tags: javascript, html, systemjs, es6-modules, lit-element

I would like to statically serve a project, that uses webcomponents (using lit-html), *without any packaging tools like webpack etc*.

The example project is composed of this structure:

```
index.html
app.js
package.json
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "lit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.7",
    "lit-element": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

`app.js`:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class FooElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<div>hello world!</div>`;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('x-foo', FooElement);
```

and finally, `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

I serve this using a static http server and, of course, this doesn't work. The browser raises the error: `Error resolving module specifier: lit-element`.

So we try altering the `import` directive to:

`import { LitElement, html } from './node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js';`

The browser then fails with: `Error resolving module specifier: lit-html` in `lit-element.ts:14:29`

I've tried using `systemjs` version `3.0.1` with the following modified `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="systemjs-importmap" src="systemjs.map.json"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app');
  </script>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

and a `systemjs.map.json` file:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "app": "./app.js",
    "lit-element": "./node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js",
    "lit-html": "./node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js"
  }
}
```

When loading this (again via a static webserver), we get in Firefox:

`import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` at `app.js:1`.

In Chrome: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` at `app.js:1`

In Safari:
`Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.` at `app.js:1`

All of which suggests that `systemjs` isn't treating `app.js` as a module.

Is there anyway that we can achieve static loading of modules that have a dependency tree within `node_modules`?

I've pushed the version of the code with `systemjs` to https://github.com/dazraf/lit-test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can perhaps use something like this in your app.js

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';
```

And this in your HTML code

```
<script type="module" src="./app.js">
```

It worked for me. If you don't want to use unpkg you can download it and serve it locally.

Comment: Thanks, this may be the cleanest way of doing this! Will give it a try and respond back here.

Comment: lit-element has additional import so, local serve won't work out-of-the-box. You have to download dependency too and modify fixed import.

Comment: Yep, I found the same :-) Interesting. Suggests that the current es6 modules standard is missing something ...

Comment: I had issues with module imports with Electron. This might help https://gist.github.com/smotaal/f1e6dbb5c0420bfd585874bd29f11c43

Answer (score 1):

We have a server that does just this, and only this: https://open-wc.org/developing/owc-dev-server.html

It's simple server that does the minimal amount of work required and is specifically designed to work with the native es module loader available in all major browsers.

In the future, this should no longer be necessary when [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) are standardized.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to avoid any tools on the server side. A few reasons, relating to minimising friction in large organisations, as well as using a JVM-based high-perf HTTP2 server. I can go into it on request. In the meantime, I followed up on your suggestion re import-maps! Looks very good; some caveats. Here's an nominal implementations: https://github.com/dazraf/lit-test/tree/es-module-shims

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to blow your mind. Difficult to find, a coworker actually found it.

https://codewithhugo.com/use-es-modules-in-node-without-babel/webpack-using-esm/

Comment: Sorry, it didn't blow